# generating new nestjs module results in Error: Failed to execute command

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, nestjs

I'm using MacOS monterey with M1 chip as my operating system. installed NestJS cli using this command: `sudo npm install -g @nestjs/cli`

when creating new nest project using `nest new message` everything works fine, but when I try to create new module using this command `nest generate module messages` I face error.

why does this happen? I tried installing schematics using `npm i -g @nestjs/schematics`, I don't know if I should've installed it but this didn't help anyway.

The error I face is:

```
/Users/homayoun/training/messages/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/bin/schematics.js:338
            throw new Error(`Unknown argument ${key}. Did you mean ${(0, yargs_parser_1.decamelize)(key)}?`);
                  ^

Error: Unknown argument skipImport. Did you mean skip-import?
    at parseArgs (/Users/homayoun/training/messages/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/bin/schematics.js:338:19)
    at main (/Users/homayoun/training/messages/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/bin/schematics.js:122:49)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/homayoun/training/messages/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/bin/schematics.js:367:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Failed to execute command: node @nestjs/schematics:module --name=messages --no-dry-run --no-skipImport --language="ts" --sourceRoot="src" --spec.
```

worth noting that I don't face any issues when I do the same thing on ubuntu 20 or 22

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Quick solution:

1. add this to your nest-cli.json

```
"root": "src"
```

2. change into the src of your project folder

```
cd src
```

3. run

```
nest generate module messages
```

if the above does not work also try changing the version of packages in package.json to

```
"@nestjs/cli": "8.2.6",
"@nestjs/schematics": "8.0.11",
```

removing the node modules in the current project
reinstalling the nest cli with

```
npm uninstall -g @nestjs/cli
npm i -g @nestjs/cli@8.2.6
```

Comment: @nestjs/cli version 8.2.7 doesn't work well.
It did help.
But you must remove the `^` from the version to make your solution work.

Answer (score 6):

this is a bug on the latest version of `@nestjs/cli` (v8.2.7). Downgrade it to `8.2.6` and it will work (I tested it). It was reported here: https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/1693

Also, I don't recommend using the global version of the CLI. Instead, use `npx nest` or `yarn nest`.